# differentiating browsing sessions between child tabs in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, cookies, chromium

I am trying to write a feature in my chrome extension that behaves like the SessionBox or MultiLogin chrome extensions. My main stump at the moment is differentiating cookies between the different child tabs such that they maintain their own individual sessions. When session cookies are updated by some interaction with a website on one tab, that is propagated to other tabs accessing the same website, due to the shared cookie store.

I have tried a few things.

1. Having a main child tab array in the extension page that houses each tab object by its id, storing cookies associated with that tab's current url. I am having trouble though differentiating site cookie update events between tabs on the same website though, as these updates are to the whole browser's cookie store and not tab based.
2. Utilizing chrome profiles, as having several child windows, each with a different chrome profile assigned to it, would accomplish the goal. The issue I'm having though is programmatically creating these chrome profiles. This was possible at one point, but was removed from chrome's api, and the only way for this method to work would be having the user manually create chrome profiles. I want this to be completely seamless, with no more user interaction than necessary.
3. Utilizing incognito child windows. Originally, I thought that each incognito window was its own browsing session with unique cookies from other incognito windows accessing the same webpage. Unfortunately, incognito windows all share the same cookies with each other. So incognito doesn't actually isolate the window from all others, just from windows running in non incognito mode.
4. I also looked into sandboxing, but that just outright didn't seem the way to go.

So far, it looks like further implementation of option 1 would be the best way to go, but I am a bit stumped on that. Secondarily, option 2 could potentially work, but is not ideal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.